# How can I remove an event listener in a class?

Tags: javascript

Why is this not removing the event listeners when I click the button? I've already assigned the functions to variables and used those as parameters, but it still wont work. What am I doing wrong? I'm very new to working with classes, so the problem might be there.

```
class InputHandler{
constructor(){
    this.down = this.keyDown.bind(this);
    this.up = this.keyUp.bind(this);

    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.down);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", this.up);

    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", this.onClick);
}

keyDown(event){
    //do stuff
}

keyUp(event){
    //do stuff
}

onClick(){
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.down);
    document.removeEventListener("keyup", this.up);
}
```

}

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. WHAT are you trying to do and WHY do you want to remove the eventListener ?

Comment: I'm replicating pong in javascript. I'm trying to figure out a way to stop the player from moving the paddles for a while when someone scores. I think removing the event listeners would accomplish this. The button is just for testing and debugging purposes.

Comment: Please do not remove and add listeners. Set a state and test it in the listener

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify? I'm not really sure what you mean by set a state.

Comment: `keyDown(event) { if (this.okToMove)   /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: Ok, I can try that. Thanks